# REST Error 400: Required request part 'uploadInfo' is not present

Tags: java, post, rest

Есть такой метод:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public @ResponseBody ServiceResponse regDocs(
          @RequestPart("uploadInfo") UploadInfo uploadInfo, 
          MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
...
}
```

Класс `UploadInfo` в свою очередь также состоит из классов.
Я пытаюсь вызвать этот метод `POST` через Advanced REST-client(это плагин для Chrome), 
указываю адрес: http://host:9080/services/request
Мне непонятно где указывать значения этого класса?
Пробовал писать json что-то вроде

```
{
   "uploadInfo":[{
    "Class1":"value",
    "Class2":"value",
    ...
   }]
}
```

пробовал ещё несколько вариантов, все время пишет

> **Error 400: Required request part 'uploadInfo' is not present.**

В каком месте нужно заполнить `uploadInfo`?

Comment: Ну обычно вроде формируется страничка (например Jsp) в которой Вы формируете свой POST запрос и ставите поля этой странички в соответствие с полями Вашего объекта UploadInfo. В принципе в любом HowTo это есть. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: Да, у нас есть самописное приложение, которое тестирует этот функционал. Но нашему боссу это не нравится, ему надо чтобы тестировалось через этот плагин для хрома.

Comment: Там, очевидно, не application/json принимается на вход, а multipart/form-data или x-www-form-urlencoded, они по-другому серализуются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

статут 400 [говорит](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP), что это плохой запрос, а плохой он из-за неправильных хидеров. в `@RequestMapping` надо добавить нужный хидер, например так: `@RequestMapping(value = "/request", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")` и на клиенте добавить в запрос нужный хидер `Content-Type: application/json`

про [@RequestMapping](http://ru.java.wikia.com/wiki/@RequestMapping)

> Параметр consumes определяет тип содержимого тела запроса. например, consumes="application/json" определяет, что Content-Type запроса, который отправил клиент должен быть "application/json". Можно задать отрицательное указание: consumes="!application/json". Тогда будет требоваться любой Content-Type, кроме указанного. допускается указание нескольких значений: ("text/plain", "application/*).
>
> Параметр produces определяет формат возвращаемого методом значения. Если на клиенте в header'ах не указан заголовок Accept, то не имеет значение, что установлено в produces. Если же заголовок Accept установлен, то значение produces должно совпадать с ним для успешного возвращения результата клиенту. Параметр produces может также содержать перечисление значений.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую